# Easier way to merge into one string output from gregexpr?

Tags: r

I am trying to merge into one string all the indices for when a `key` appears in a `string`. I came up with the following. But I was wondering if there is an easier/shorter way?

```
mystring = "ASDAS ap ASDASD ap AS"
key = "ap"
x = paste(as.data.frame(gregexpr(key, mystring))[1:nrow(as.data.frame(gregexpr(key, mystring))),], collapse=", ")
```

The output looks like follows:

```
> x
[1] "7, 17"
```

Comment: `toString(gregexpr(key, mystring)[[1]])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want something like the following:

```
paste(gregexpr(key, mystring)[[1]], collapse = ', ')
#[1] "7, 17"
```

Simply using `[[1]]` to subset the gregexpr output should be enough.